# why yum could not find the python-pip packages on some PCs

Tags: python, yum, centos7, epel, pip

I got a very strange problem and cannot figure out why.

When I run `yum info python-pip` command on some CentOS 7 machines, it returns **Error: No matching Packages to list**. But, I used to install python-pip on without problem until now.

epel repository is enabled:

```
epel/x86_64                  Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64      11,016
```

Strangely, the same command can run successfully on other CentOS 7 servers and returns the information of the package.

CentOS release: **CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)**
epel-release: **7.6** or **7.8** (I tried both.)

Please someone could explain what is wrong the EPEL repository.

**EDIT:**
The yum command output;

```
[root@local ~]# yum info python-pip  
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks  
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  
 * epel: fedora.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au  
 * rpmforge: mirror.ventraip.net.au  
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

**EDIT2:**
It may be just because of the package has been pulled out from the repository. But I still don't understand why some servers are able to see and download the package but others not.
I have run through the commands below on both servers and the check-update shows that the epel repository is from *fedora.uberglobalmirror.com*, which is same on both servers.

```
yum clean all
yum check-update
yum info python-pip`
```

Comment: What is the _complete_ output from `yum info python-pip`?

Comment: sorry to be late. I didn't notice the comment and serverfault shows no reply. anyway, following the result of the command:   
`# yum info python-pip
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: fedora.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au
 * rpmforge: mirror.ventraip.net.au
Error: No matching Packages to list`

Answer (score 3):

Hmm. A careful examination of my EPEL mirror shows that the package is now named `python2-pip` beginning with EPEL 7.

```
/srv/www/mirrors/epel/7/x86_64/p/python2-pip-8.1.2-5.el7.noarch.rpm
```

I would suggest that you try installing that.

Comment: thanks Michael, the python2-pip seems doing the job. I just don't understand why some servers can see the package but others not. I was wondering I might miss something.

Comment: Huh.. Good find. I didn't notice that. I definitely have a python-pip in my local mirror that keeps old copies. It's in Koji as python-pip, too.

Comment: @AaronCopley I don't have space to keep old copies on my mirror, but I don't doubt it. Renaming all the `python-` packages to `python2-` has been in progress for quite a while now, as Python 3 will finally become the default Python in RHEL 8. But since EPEL packages are often maintained in sync with corresponding Fedora packages, most of which have already been renamed...

Answer (score 0):

You can always review a Yum mirror [via your web browser](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7Server/x86_64/p/) to determine if it is a Yum problem, or if the package is missing from the mirror. In this case, it looks like the package is missing. Nothing is wrong with Yum. Your other systems may have cached repository data, or might be connecting to a different mirror with an outdated package list.

The next step would be to check the mailing lists and [BugZilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com) to see if there has been any discussion.

I am actually not sure which mailing list would be correct here;

- [epel-devel](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/admin/lists/epel-devel@lists.fedoraproject.org/)
- [epel-announce](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/admin/lists/epel-announce@lists.fedoraproject.org/)
- [epel-package-announce](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/admin/lists/epel-package-announce@lists.fedoraproject.org/)

I was able to find a conversation on BugZilla that *might* be related: [pip install is broken (path/permissions)](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1406133) Maybe the package was pulled due to this. It doesn't seem like a serious issue..

If you cannot wait for this to be resolved, you might be able to find an older, unaffected version in [Koji](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=9400), the build system. (Check what version is installed and working on other systems.)

Lastly, it seems the [SRPM](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/SRPMS/p/) is still available. You could grab it and rebuild it yourself to see if it will meet your needs. Though, if it was pulled, maybe there is good reason.

Comment: It looks like the package has been pulled out. but why some servers can still see it or able to install it? I have done "yum clean all" to clean all the caches.

Comment: Best guess is not all mirrors are configured the same way and caching.